# Why is a predictive distribution wider than mean response distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Why is a predictive distribution wider than a mean response distribution?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking about? Are you asking about the relative widths of confidence intervals vs predictive intervals?

Comment: @gung yes that is correct, relative width of confidence intervals vs predictive interval.